# How do I run a BAT script without changing directories?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

How do I run a BAT script without changing directories?

I am in `./a` and the script cd's into `./a/bc`. If I need to terminate my script for whatever reason I am now in `bc` instead of `a`. How do I run the script and not have my folder change?

Also, I don't like how it asks me if I'd like to terminate my script. Can I disable that and let it terminate?

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to propagate environment variable changes into the current environment *and* cannot touch the batch file (to use the `pushd`/`popd` variant which I usually use), you can still spawn a new instance of `cmd`:

```
cmd /c myBatch.cmd arg1 arg2 ...
```

Also has the nice property of leaving your original batch file running even if the called batch throws up errors. I do that in my batch unit testing framework, for example, to ensure that a failing batch file won't stop the tests from executing.

Answer (score 5):

The **setlocal** command is useful for this.  Any directory changes after **setlocal** are just local to the batch script.  BTW this also applies to any environment variables (**set** commands).

For example, after running this batch script:

```
cd /d c:\temp
setlocal
cd /d c:\windows
```

the directory will be c:\temp since the second cd in the script is just local to the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your script with `start yourscript.bat`. This makes it run in a new command window, and therefore does not affect the working directory of the command prompt that started the script.

Another possibility is to *not use* `cd` and use absolute paths instead.

Comment: start opens a new cmd prompt which i have to close everytime which is somewhat annoying. This might do tho

Answer (score 2):

The first question is: why do you need to change the directory? Can you simply work with paths relative to the one of your batch file? (e.g. using `%~dp0\a\bc` to reference the directory)

But if you really, really need to do that, you can do the following:

```
REM change the current directory
pushd ..\a\bc

.. do your stuff here

REM restore the old "current directory"
popd
```

Comment: so i can just use popd... i think i'l use this.

Comment: Yes, simply `popd`. It's a stack. For each pushd, you need to call popd. But it won't address your problem when the user terminates the batch file using Ctrl-C